# How can I mock a function that isn't called by name?

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, python-decorators, pytest-mock

Suppose I have a decorator that collects all the functions it decorates to be called at some point in the future.

**mydecorator.py**

```
class CallLater(object):
    funcs = []

    def __init__(self, func):
        self.funcs.append(func)

    @classmethod
    def call_now(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        for func in cls.funcs:
            func(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then, I have a function in a module, one of which will be saved by my decorator.

**mymodule.py**

```
import logging

from mydecorator import CallLater

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO) 

@CallLater
def log_a():
    logging.info("A")

@CallLater
def log_b():
    logging.info("B")

def log_c():
    logging.info("C")
```

Now, if I import `mymodule` and call `CallLater.call_now()`, `log_a` and `log_b` will be called. But let's say that during testing, I want `log_b` to be substituted with `log_c`. I'll try to do the replacement with a mock.

**mock_test.py**

```
import logging
import pytest

from mymodule import log_a, log_c
from mydecorator import CallLater

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO) 
pytest_plugins = ('pytest_mock',)

def test_mocking(mocker, caplog):
    mocker.patch('mymodule.log_b', log_c)

    CallLater.call_now()

    logs = [rec.message for rec in caplog.records]
    assert logs == ["A", "C"]
```

But when I run `pytest`, I see that my mock didn't work.

```
FAILED mock_test.py::test_mocking - AssertionError: assert ['A', 'B'] == ['A', 'C']
```

I imagine that `'mymodule.log_b'` is the wrong mocking target since it's not being invoked as `mymodule.log_b()`, but I'm not sure what to use instead in this situation. Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: For reference, this question was inspired by wanting to disable [SQLAlchemy event listeners](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/events.html#mapper-events), which seems to be better handled by calling `sqlalchemy.event.remove`, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40244861/4228052)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible as such, the problem being that the functions are already assigned to the list at load time. The only way I can see to patch this would be to patch `CallLater.funcs` directly, which is a bit awkward, because you have to replace `log_b` by `log_c` manually - but here it goes:

```
import logging
from unittest import mock

from mymodule import log_c
from mydecorator import CallLater

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)


def test_mocking(caplog):
    funcs = [log_c if f.__name__ == 'log_b' else f for f in CallLater.funcs]
    with mock.patch.object(CallLater, 'funcs', funcs):
        CallLater.call_now()

        logs = [rec.message for rec in caplog.records]
        assert logs == ["A", "C"]
```

Note that you cannot compare directly to the function (e.g. `f == log_b`), because `log_b` is the decorated function, not the function as saved in `CallLater.funcs`.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I wasn't considering when the list of functions was being created. Thanks for your quick and clear response!

Comment: Glad I could help!